# addEventListener not modifying href on click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change href attributes of specific classes onclick. However, the original href never changes.

```
<a class="vendor" href="https://jsfiddle.net">JSFiddle.net</a>
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", fixlinks);

function fixlinks() {
  var link_class = document.getElementsByClassName("vendor")
  for (var i = 0; i < link_class.length; i++) {
    link_class[i].addEventListener("click", makeLinks(link_class[i]));
  }
}

function makeLinks(expr) {
  //RickRoll 'em
  expr.setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ");
}
```

[//jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/5/)

Comment: There's no `class="vendor"` in your anchor.

Comment: The JSFiddle works fine if instead of executing [onload](http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/5/), you place it with [no wrap in body](http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/8/)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for not looking at my JSFiddle, your comment was really helpful.

Comment: @Barmar How is this question a duplicate of that other question? They have literally nothing in common.

Comment: @Baskervor http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/7/

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question it is marked a duplicate of. The issue that OP is facing is that is binding an action to an event that has already happened and then it will not execute. It doesn't have to do with the scope of any variable

Comment: If he rewrites his code like the answer there, he'll get correct code. His code has two problems: the scope of `i` and he's also not binding to the function.

Comment: @Barmar That's not true. Baskervor: check http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/10/, I have added comments for you.

Comment: Change `makeLinks(link_class[i])` to `makeLinks`, and then `expr.setAttribute(...` to `this.setAttribute(...`

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't the scope of `i` be correct? OP is passing the element and not using `i` inside of `makeLinks`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro The problem is that he's calling `makeLinks` when the page is loaded, not when the link is clicked on.

Comment: @j08691: Nothing will happen on click, which is clearly the intent.

Comment: Apologize for poor grammar; sincerely, thank you for pointing to duplicate, it helps.

Comment: @Barmar is correct in the sense that it feels like an incorrect attempt at the solution in the duplicate. However, that solution doesn't make sense here since all he needs is reference to the bound element.

Comment: @Barmar The issue is that 1. the `onload` handler doesnt fire when the `readyState` of the `document` is `complete` and 2. the `makeLinks` method doesn't return a function. He doesn't have any scoping issues. The dup link doesn't provide an answer for that.

Comment: The dup link shows the correct way to write `fixlinks`.

Comment: I give in, I've reopened the question.

Comment: @Barmar I can't see that the "correct" way is mentioned on the dup link. Neither does it mention the document.readyState or why the onload handler doesn't fire nor does any of the functions over there return a callback for the listener but instead they set the listeners in their callbacks.  Besides all of them look like bad practice. // edit, okay nvm, you reopened the question :P

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem with the `onload` handler?

Comment: @Barmar: It's a result of him using jsFiddle with the default `onload` menu set. A handler bound after the `window.onload` has already fired won't be invoked. It probably has nothing to do with the actual issue.

Comment: @Barmar Because he linked a fiddle in his question. As this might not be an issue in other environments, it at least answers why his code doesn't work in the fiddle which he used to express his issue. But I guess you are right, in 99% of the cases this won't be an actual issue..

Comment: This is why jsFiddle demos suck so horribly bad. Everyone wants the asker to make a demo, but we then don't know if new problems were introduced or not. A simple yet complete code example in the question is all that's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to not invoke the function but pass it instead, and use `this` to reference the bound element in the handler.

*Updated DEMO:* http://jsfiddle.net/qm9bnvon/11/

```
window.addEventListener("load",fixlinks);

function fixlinks() {
    var link_class = document.getElementsByClassName("vendor")
    for(var i = 0; i < link_class.length; i++) { // v----pass it, don't invoke it
        link_class[i].addEventListener("click", makeLinks);
    }
}

function makeLinks(event) {
//   v---`this` refers to the bound element
    this.setAttribute("href","https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `document.readyState` property is `complete` then the `onload` handler will not fire. (This at least is the case for jsfiddle, which you linked in your question).
So you need to check for both cases:

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    fixlinks();
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load",fixlinks);
}
```

The next issue is that you are not setting a callback in your click listener.
Because `makeLinks` doesn't return a function for the click handler to invoke:

```
function fixlinks() {
    var link_class = document.getElementsByClassName("vendor")
    for(var i = 0; i < link_class.length; i++) {
        link_class[i].addEventListener("click",makeLinks(link_class[i]));
    }
}

// here we return the callback
function makeLinks(expr) {
    //RickRoll 'em
    return function() {
        expr.setAttribute("href","https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ");
    };
}
```

Comment: This is a terribly over-engineered solution. Doesn't make any sense to return a function that closes over an element that you have direct access to as the bound element anyway.

Comment: That depends on what he intends to do with `makeLinks`method. He set it up in the way that the element was passed as an argument, so I guess he has his reasons to do so.

Comment: Could one not simply:

    return expr.setAttribute("href","http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcq")

Comment: @Baskervor But that is not a function. All listeners expect a function as callback.

Comment: Since makeLinks is function does that not automatically call back to listener?

Guess W3 is bad school http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp shows lots in same method without "return"

Comment: @Baskervor Yes, w3schools is generally bad. However, in this case all their eventlisteners do have a function as second parameter. The difference is that you are invoking `makeLinks` which doesn't have a return value.